# No value specified for parameter 8

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Im reading each line of text from a file and inserting into a database using a dynamic query. Each file is named as per the table name, so I get the column names and types to build the query and then just insert the values.
When Ive had to insert a NULL value Ive been running into issues and cant see what Im missing?
According to the printed lines Im seeing 8 ? marks and 8 values but the error message says: *No value specified for parameter 8.*

Generated Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.request_service_log (request_service_log_id, request_service_id, severity_cde, log_cde, log_txt, source_id, message_id, application_id) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Parameter Values:

```
23584022,222635,C,10002002,Start Monitor Failed,0,25431082,NULL
```

Code:

```
public void insertData(String tableName, List<String> rows) {
    List<String> columnNames = null;
    try{
        //get the column names and types for the specified table
        columnNames = getColumns(tableName, "dbo");
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
        System.out.println(se.getMessage());
    }

    String insertColumns = "";
    String insertValues = "";

    for(int i =0; i < columnNames.size(); i++){
        if(i == 0){
            insertColumns += columnNames.get(i);
        }
        else {
            insertColumns += ", " + columnNames.get(i);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++){
        if((i + 1) < columnNames.size()){
            insertValues += "?, ";
        }
        else {
            insertValues += "?";
        }

    }

    String insertSql = "INSERT INTO dbo." + tableName + " (" + insertColumns + ") values(" + insertValues + ")";
    System.out.println(insertSql);
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql);
        try{
            int index = 0;
            for(String row : rows){
                index++;
                System.out.println(index + ": " + row);
                String[] items = row.split(",");
                for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    if(StringUtils.isInteger(columnTypes.get(i))){
                        if("NULL".equalsIgnoreCase(items[i])){
                            ps.setNull((1 +1), Types.INTEGER);
                        }
                        else {
                            ps.setInt((i + 1), new Integer(items[i]).intValue());
                        }
                    }
                    else if(StringUtils.isVarchar(columnTypes.get(i))) {
                        if("NULL".equalsIgnoreCase(items[i])){
                            ps.setNull((i + 1), Types.VARCHAR);
                        }
                        else {
                            ps.setString((i + 1), items[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(StringUtils.isDatetime((columnTypes.get(i)))){
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss");
                        java.util.Date date = null;
                        try {
                            date = formatter.parse(items[i]);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if(date == null){
                            ps.setNull((i +1), Types.TIMESTAMP);
                        }
                        else {
                            ps.setTimestamp((i + 1), new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()));
                        }
                    }
                }
                ps.executeUpdate(); //insert our data
            }

        }
        catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println(se.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
        //do something with it
        System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(ps != null){
                ps.close();
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, post your stack trace

Comment: you have a line with a mistake: `ps.setNull((1 +1), Types.INTEGER);`, its needed to change to `ps.setNull((i +1), Types.INTEGER);`

Comment: `ps.setNull((1 +1), Types.INTEGER);` should be `ps.setNull((i+1), Types.INTEGER);`

Comment: Thanks @Danilo a second pair of eyes is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this problem when `items`, the result of `split(',')` call, yields fewer than eight items.

You should fix this by iterating `i` from 0 to 7, inclusive, and checking that `items` has enough elements to cover `i`:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 8 ; i++) {
    String item = (items.length() < i) ? items[i] : "NULL";
    ... // Now use item instead of items[i] below
}
```

Comment: Nice point @dasblinkenlight thanks for pointing out a safety net solution.